# asp.net core appsettings.json in github

Tags: asp.net-core, github, config, appsettings

I have a couple of projects built using ASP.NET Core 3 which I develop on localhost and publish to my shared Windows hosting account.

I want to put the above mentioned projects into GitHub in Public repositiories, but the problem is the appsettings.json file has the connection to the SQL Server database that is on the shared hosting.

Is there any way to get around this information showing in appsettings.json when pushed to GitHub?

I have read about using Secrets in appsettings.json but I don't think I could use the Secrets on the shared Windows hosting (unless I am missing something obvious there).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to use environment specific configuration, like environment variables or the secret manager (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configuration-by-environment)), you can create an own repository for deployment which contains the production appsettings file (containing sensitive information like the connection string). You could push to both repositories, or keep the repositories in sync automatically e.g. using [GitLab's Repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html) (if hosting the private repositories there is an option).